# Gulp watch deleting css on second run

Tags: sass, gulp-watch, codeanywhere

I'm using CodeAnywhere (cloud IDE) and installing gulp. Running 'gulp sass' works fine every time, but when I 'gulp watch' the 'sass' task runs fine the first time. After that it just creates an empty style.css file. I'm following the '[gulp for beginners](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)' post on css-tricks.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
})
```

My file structure is laid out as follows:
[image]

Comment: Is this your whole gulpfile? If your output css file is empty it sounds more like your source scss is also empty or at least doesn't contain any css and only has variables or something. On another note, you probably want to output the css file to another directory like `/dist` rather than `/src`. That way you can clean the `/dist` directory each time you rebuild

Comment: Switching the directory seemed to do the trick. Thanks